# Weird formatting with CSS and HTML

Tags: css

When I use `margin-top:-50px;` on this div, why does it indent the text at http://fluroltd.com/clients/harveys/ underneath the slider where it says About Harveys Electrical?

```
#news-item { margin-top:-50px; }
```

```
<div id="page">
<div id="slider">
            <ul>                
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li> </li>          
            </ul>
</div><!-- slider -->

<?php query_posts('category_name=Latest News&showposts=1'); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="news-item">
            <h1></h1>
            <?php the_content('<br/>Read More'); ?>
        </div><!-- news-item-home -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- page -->
```

Comment: Can you also post your HTML? At face value, you need something like this:
    #news-item { margin-top:-50px;}
or:
    .news-item{ margin-top:-50px;}

Comment: what browser? take a screenshot, show us the html etc. help us help you

Comment: I dont see an indent and I am using IE 7.0....

Comment: It's in Firefox, Safari and Chrome are ok and so is IE 7.0 according to Chugh97 (Thanks)

Comment: @Andrew @Saladin - Sigh... why can't you guys actually be bothered to actually go down to the site, and find the offending `div`? I mean, he's already given all the info you need, hasn't he?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `float` problem. Normal elements in the document flow give way to `float`ed elements when the float elements overlap them. You can confirm this by giving `#news-item` a `clear` CSS property, and watch the indent disappear.

There is a fix for it, but it's a bit of a kludge. Use these CSS rules:

```
#news-item {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
}
```

However, to actually solve the problem, you need to find the offending element.

Comment: It's in Firefox, Safari and Chrome are ok and so is IE 7.0 according to Chugh97 (Thanks)